# Avoiding PNG --> JPG image conversion for Twitter profile image

Tags: png, file-conversion

I've got a logo I'm attempting to use as a profile image for a Twitter account and unfortunately each time I upload my PNG file, it's clearly getting converted to JPG which is introducing compression artifacts. I've got it properly sized to 400x400 pixels and have played around with introducing transparent pixels into the image to prevent the conversion. But to no avail.

Anyone have any suggestions regarding approaches you've used to prevent JPG conversion?

Answer (score 5):

As others have suggested,
first: Add at least one pixel of transparency to the image (use the corners of the image, where it will be cropped to a circle anyway)

Secondly though:
Use the mobile interface to upload. Otherwise the desktop interface will convert to jpg when it asks to resize, transparency or not, resized or not.
You don't actually need to be on mobile to do this: https://mobile.twitter.com/home will do.

Comment: Thanks Freddie. I tried that as well already and sadly it does not currently work.

Comment: I also find taking the Twitter recommend image size and doubling it, helps keep compression to a minimum.

Comment: The mobile version always converts to jpg for me. Have tried on : chrome-desktop, safari-desktop, chrome-mobile, firefox-mobile, app-mobile... out of ideas now... :(

Comment: @mattburns the mobile website worked for me. I uploaded from Firefox on my desktop Windows PC. I uploaded as PNG and it stayed as PNG.

Answer (score 3):

You need to force Twitter to respect your png. And for twitter png means "transparency".

So just add 1 pixel (or line) of 1% transparency and save as truecolor PNG and it should work.

Comment: I've been saving 400x400 pixel PNG images with a transparent background and they are always converted to JPG after I upload them. Truly stumped at this point.

Comment: Beginning to think that the upload process from the Twitter web client is the issue. After the prompt to position and resize the image, it may very well be converting the image by default to JPG.